# Disable UIPanGestureRecognizer on UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `UIView` and the problem is when you tab the `UIButton`s inside the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is still enabled. How do I disable the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on just the buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a delegate for the gesture recognizer [(Reference for Delegate)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldReceiveTouch%3a). For example your view controller could be the delegate conforming to the protocol ***UIGestureRecognizerDelegate***. In that way you can use the method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

In your delegate to avoid recognizing the gesture in an specific view.

You can create your gesture and assign it to some view, in the following way (ARC supposed):

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someMethodName:)];
panGesture.delegate = self;

UIView *someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
[someView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Here you have more detailed information about how to handle gestures and also avoiding the gesture to be received on some views of your interest:

[Event handling guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html)

Basically you need to do something like the following to prevent gestures on your buttons:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
 if ([touch view] == self.myButton){
    return NO;
 }

 return YES;
}
```

Returning NO causes the gesture to fail and allow other views to proceed with the processing of the touch.

You could also check if [touch view] is kind of *UIButton*, to make it more general and avoid comparing against all your buttons.

Comment: Works perfect. The problem I had with this was that I forgot to set the PanGestureRecognizer's delegate to self.

Comment: I'll complete my response with a more detailed example, so the whole process could be seen,

Answer (score 2):

assign a delegate to the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and overwrite the method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return ! ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]);
}
```